# Instagram Oauth with Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, instagram-api, firebase-authentication

I am trying to allow the user to login with Instagram, than create a user in Firebase.

This is my code to login

```
 oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(
        NSURL(string: "Testing://oauth-callback")!,
        scope: "likes+comments", state:"INSTAGRAM",
        success: { credential, response, parameters in
            self.token = credential.oauth_token
            print(self.token)

            let TokenDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            TokenDefault.setValue(self.token, forKey: "token")




            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(self.token) { (user, error) in
                print("Im in")
                print(user)

               // self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueHome", sender: self)
            }


        },
        failure: { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

When i print user, it shows nil. And in the firebase console, it doesn't show a new user. im not sure what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

An October 2016 Firebase blog post shows exactly to do this for a Web app (using Node.js backend), and of course iOS and Android implementations would be similar. They do say to "stay tuned", presumably for another blog post specific to iOS/Android but there's nothing as of this writing.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html

Example code is here: https://github.com/firebase/custom-auth-samples

I may be doing this myself under iOS in the next few weeks, so will add more if I find any gotchas.

Comment: It appears there's an iOS version now: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with-line-login.html